# Does pattern validation differs in XSD?

Tags: java, regex, xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I am trying to validate a XML element with XSD pattern validation using below pattern and it's not working. The required behavior is to allow all characters excepts the ones mentioned in pattern expression.

```
<xsd:pattern value="^[^&gt;&lt;{}|^`\[\]\\\\]*$"/>

Valid data : TESTING
Invalid data : TE{ST]`I<NG
```

But above pattern is giving validation error for valid data(TESTING) also in XSD but same works fine if I use this pattern in java regualr expression match package. Please help.

Comment: Your character class is possibly not valid, or at least is not doing what you think.  `[&gt;]` means match any of `&`, `g`, `t`, `;`.  It does not mean match the HTML symbol `&gt;`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen You can't use `<` and `>` literals in XML. Need to use the entities instead.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen OK...but is that character class valid?  I've never seen a flavor of regex which allows for multiple characters.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen That character class is valid and will work as intended. The problem is with the `^` and `$` anchors.

Comment: I learn something new every day ^ ^.  So, the parser probably converts `&gt;` into `>` internally, to use in the class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unlike stated in multiple comments and answers to this question, entities like `&gt;` and `&lt;` can be used without any problems in XML Schema regular expressions.

However, anchors like the caret (`^`) and dollar (`$`) are not supported.

Given the following schema, with the anchors removed from the pattern:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" > 
  <xsd:element name="test" type="test"/> 

  <xsd:simpleType name="test"> 
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string"> 
      <xsd:pattern value="[^&gt;&lt;{}|^`\[\]\\\\]*"/> 
    </xsd:restriction> 
  </xsd:simpleType> 
</xsd:schema>
```

This will validate correctly:

```
<test>testing</test>
```

While these will not:

```
<test>{testing</test>

<test>&gt;testing</test>
```